# If X is measurable in the completion of F, does there exist F-measurable Y such that X = Y a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory

Let the underlying probability space be $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Suppose I have a sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{A}$ and a random element $X$ such that $X$ is measurable in the completion of $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to $P$.

Does there exist a random element $Y$ such that $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $X = Y$ a.s.? If not in general, what are sufficient conditions for this to be the case? (I think if $X$ takes values in a separable metric space, it is true, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, found my own answer. It's in Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability, Lemma 1.25.

A sufficient condition is for $X$ to take values in a Borel space.

Then a proof can proceed by showing it for indicator functions measurable with respect to the completion, then approximation of any measurable function by simple functions that agree a.s.